# Why does TextView.setText() warn you not to concatenate strings?

Tags: android, string, textview, settext

If I do something like this

```
someTextView.setText(someString + " and more!");
```

it warns me "Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string with placeholders."

Why does it warn this when string concatenation seems to work just fine?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use resource strings thinking about localization

Answer (score 0):

That is a [Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html) tool running an inspection for you.